# ubuntu hang out with this message :blocked for more than 120 seconds

Tags: server, kernel, webserver

I'm running a virtualMachine on ESXi -- Ubuntu as a webserver -- (apache2 with nginx as his proxy, php, mysql) and services keeps hanging/freezing causing the whole server to be unresponsive. It's not possible to connect to it by ssh, basicly it requires a reboot from vSphere to come back online.

Description: Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS Release: 10.04 Codename: lucid

at vSphere I see this message when my server is unreachable:: **INFO: task: apache2 (or mysql or nginx) blocked for more than 120 seconds. "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_sys_timeout_secs" disables this message**

i think that likely it happens in high traffic on my sites what could i do?!

thanks

Comment: any idea pro guys??!

Comment: I think it is probably Apache its self hanging.  Do you have any syslog entries related to the problem, or from around the hang?

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting a hung task time out, while your system is waiting for some resources (maybe I/O to complete) to complete which are not presently available. I would recommend first collecting some data checking with any sar data or using tools like iostats and vmstat to identify the loads and the times the freeze/hang occurs. You could possibly write a small cron job for this.

ex:
sar -A 1 30 > /tmp/sar_-A.out.txt &
vmstat 1 30 > /tmp/vmstat.out.txt &
iostat -tkx 1 30 > /tmp/iostat_-x.out.txt & 
ps aufx > /tmp/ps_aux.out.txt &

Also get a kernel thread dump using: "echo t | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger" as this would help in determining to some extent what the apache process is waiting for.

Alternatively, you could get configure [crashdump](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe) when your system is in a hung state and obtain a vmcore file, if you are more adventurous to do a dump analysis.